# Problem with the Table function when adding together

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I am a newbie, I have a problem with `Table`. Can anyone explain to me understand?
For example, I did the expression `Qk1`, `Qk2` with table function such :

```
Qk1=Table[A[[i+1,1]].B,{i,0,4]  
Qk2=Table[C[[i+1,1]].D,{i,0,4]
Qk=Qk1+Qk2
```

When I call again `Qk` to calculate another expression `Mk=Qk[[i+1,1]].X`, it only understands that `Qk` is `Qk1`. If I change `Qk[[i+1,1]]` to `Qk[[i+1,2]]` it understands that `Qk` now is `Qk2`.

For clarity:
Results from `Qk1={a,b,c,d}`, and `Qk2={e,f,g,h}` => `Qk={a+e,b+f,c+g,d+h}`

When calculating `Mk=Qk[[i+1,1]].X` the result is `Mk={ax,bx,cx,dx}` while `Mk=Qk[[i+1,2]].X` the result is `Mk={ex,fx,gx,hx}`.
Following logically,It should be `Mk={(a+e)x,(b+f)x,(c+g)x,(d+h)x}`

P/s: Edited. This is my original code: As we can see, the results Mok is not logically because `Qk[[i+1,1]]` in this expression is not same with Qk that I calculated before, it is same with Qk1

```
 `Qk1 = Table[-Fk[[i + 1, 1]]*Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], k + 1][[i + 1, 1]]]/
  Sin[Subscript[\[Gamma], k][[i + 1, 1]]], {i, 0, 4}]`

  `{-F0 Cos[\[Phi]1] Csc[\[Gamma]0], -F1 Cos[\[Phi]2] Csc[\[Gamma]1], \
  -F2 Cos[\[Phi]3] Csc[\[Gamma]2], -F3 Cos[\[Phi]4] Csc[\[Gamma]3], -F4 \
   Cos[\[Phi]5] Csc[\[Gamma]4]}`

`Qk2 = Table[Fk[[i + 1, 1]]*Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], k][[i + 1, 1]]]/
 Sin[Subscript[\[Gamma], k][[i + 1, 1]]], {i, 0, 4}]`

`{F0 Cos[\[Gamma]0 - \[Phi]1] Csc[\[Gamma]0], 
 F1 Cos[\[Gamma]1 - \[Phi]2] Csc[\[Gamma]1], 
 F2 Cos[\[Gamma]2 - \[Phi]3] Csc[\[Gamma]2], 
 F3 Cos[\[Gamma]3 - \[Phi]4] Csc[\[Gamma]3], 
 F4 Cos[\[Gamma]4 - \[Phi]5] Csc[\[Gamma]4]}`

`Qk = Total[{Qk1, Qk2}]`

`{F0 Cos[\[Gamma]0 - \[Phi]1] Csc[\[Gamma]0] - 
 F0 Cos[\[Phi]1] Csc[\[Gamma]0], 
 F1 Cos[\[Gamma]1 - \[Phi]2] Csc[\[Gamma]1] - 
 F1 Cos[\[Phi]2] Csc[\[Gamma]1], 
 F2 Cos[\[Gamma]2 - \[Phi]3] Csc[\[Gamma]2] - 
 F2 Cos[\[Phi]3] Csc[\[Gamma]2], 
 F3 Cos[\[Gamma]3 - \[Phi]4] Csc[\[Gamma]3] - 
 F3 Cos[\[Phi]4] Csc[\[Gamma]3], 
 F4 Cos[\[Gamma]4 - \[Phi]5] Csc[\[Gamma]4] - 
 F4 Cos[\[Phi]5] Csc[\[Gamma]4]}`

`M0k[x_] = Table[Qk [[i + 1, 1]] (L1^2 - 4 x^2)/8, {i, 0, 4}]`

`{1/8 F0 (L1^2 - 4 x^2) Cos[\[Gamma]0 - \[Phi]1] Csc[\[Gamma]0], 
 1/8 F1 (L1^2 - 4 x^2) Cos[\[Gamma]1 - \[Phi]2] Csc[\[Gamma]1], 
 1/8 F2 (L1^2 - 4 x^2) Cos[\[Gamma]2 - \[Phi]3] Csc[\[Gamma]2], 
 1/8 F3 (L1^2 - 4 x^2) Cos[\[Gamma]3 - \[Phi]4] Csc[\[Gamma]3], 
 1/8 F4 (L1^2 - 4 x^2) Cos[\[Gamma]4 - \[Phi]5] Csc[\[Gamma]4]}`
```

Comment: The expression `Mk=Qk[[i+1,1]].X` has an undefined $i$, so it shouldn't work as-is. Was this used inside a Table? Can you show your complete code with the definitions of A, B, X? Also please explain what your actual ultimate goal is; there might be a more direct approach.

Comment: The code that you show could not possibly evaluate. The syntax of the `Table` commands is wrong and both symbols `C` and `D` are reserved. When posting code, paste the actual code used that is causing problems. Also provide all definitions required for the code to evaluate.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/hhcmefb5tn9obi3/TARCZOWNICA+-+Copy+-+Copy.nb/file
I so sorry I am uploading the original file which I am working. As I said above. When calculating the Mk=Qk[[i+1,1]].X , Qk[[i+1,1]] is understood Qk1. 
You can see my file Qk in Mok is Qk'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten the closing curly braces in the Table. Adding them, and taking into account what Bob Hanlon has written one can do as follows

```
Qk1 = Table[a[[i + 1, 1]].b, {i, 0, 4}] // Quiet
Qk2 = Table[c[[i + 1, 1]].d, {i, 0, 4}] // Quiet
Qk = Qk1 + Qk2


(* {a[[1, 1]].b, a[[2, 1]].b, a[[3, 1]].b, a[[4, 1]].b, a[[5, 1]].b}

{c[[1, 1]].d, c[[2, 1]].d, c[[3, 1]].d, c[[4, 1]].d, c[[5, 1]].d}

{a[[1, 1]].b + c[[1, 1]].d, a[[2, 1]].b + c[[2, 1]].d, 
 a[[3, 1]].b + c[[3, 1]].d, a[[4, 1]].b + c[[4, 1]].d, 
 a[[5, 1]].b + c[[5, 1]].d}

*)
```

Is it what you expected?

Comment: Sorry I have forgotten the closing curly braces in the Table but in my file is ok. But come back to my goal. I am asking why when I do the calculation Mk=Qk[[i+1,1]].X, Qk[[i+1,1]] is understood as Qk1 while I had already calculated Qk=Qk1+Qk2 before. So I dont know what happened?

Comment: Please see my original code.

Comment: Such things usually happen if you have already assigned Qk to Qk1  somewhere previously in the code during your actual Mathematica session. It helps if before the definitions of Qk1 and Qk2 you put `Clear[Qk,Qk1,Qk2]`. Another way would be to close-reopen Mathematica. In particular, for me the calculation of Mk works as expected. I should add that the aim of your calculation is quite unclear. Apriory Mathematica does not know, what are objects you denote as A, B, C, ..., X, Fk. What are their structures? Hence there are warning messages. Do you (maybe) mean to describe arrays in such a way?

Comment: You can see that Mok[1,1] is not same Qk[1,1]x(L1^2 - 4 x^2)/8